# Understanding these Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

There is a variable being set as follows (through custom tag invocation)

```
<cfset str = Trim( THISTAG.GeneratedContent ) />
```

The contents of THISTAG.GeneratedContent looks like

```
FNAME|MNAME|LNAME Test|Test|Test
```

The code I am having trouble understanding is as follows:

```
<cfset str = str.ReplaceAll(
            "(?m)^[\t ]+|[\t ]+$",
            ""
            ) />

<cfset arrRows = str.Split( "[\r\n]+" ) />
```

The above line of code should generate array with contents as

```
arrRows[1] = FNAME|MNAME|LNAME
arrRows[2] = Test|Test|Test
```

But on dumping the array shows following output:

```
FNAME|MNAME|LNAME Test|Test|Test
```

I do not understand what both regular expressions are trying to achieve.

Comment: what do you get when you output str inside a pre tag or textarea or anything else that will show carraige returns?

Comment: _"The contents of THISTAG.GeneratedContent looks like"_  - your split code relies on there being newlines (or carriage returns) between the piped sections, which you doesn't appear in what you've posted - you need to check what the custom tag is doing and why it's not outputting line breaks.

Comment: btw a quick answer to what the two regexes are doing: the first is removing any tabs/spaces that are at the beginning or end of lines, the second one is converting lines to an array

Comment: Thanks Peter. The second line of code is spltting based on carriage return/line feed, but the output did not have these. Adding a carriage return has solved my issue.

Comment: @PeterBoughton Could you submit your comment as answer so that I can accept it...What you have commented has helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one...

```
<cfset str = str.ReplaceAll(
    "(?m)^[\t ]+|[\t ]+$",
    ""
    ) />
```

..is removing any tabs/spaces that are at the beginning or end of lines. The `(?m)` turns on multiline mode which causes `^` to match "start of line" (as opposed to its usual "start of content"), and similarly `$` means "end of line" (rather than "end of content") in this mode.

This one...

```
<cfset arrRows = str.Split( "[\r\n]+" ) />
```

...is converting lines to an array, by splitting on any combination of consecutive carriage returns and/or newline characters.

**Bonus Info**

You can actually combine these two regexes into a single one, like so:

```
<cfset arrRows = str.split( '\s*\n\s*' ) />
```

The `\s` will match any  whitespace character - i.e. `[\r\n\t ]` and thus this combines the removal of spaces and tabs with turning it into an array.
*(Note that since it works by looking for newlines, the `trim` on GeneratedContent is necessary for any preceeding/trailing whitespace to be removed.)*